# Como cambiar el fondo y la letra de un menú bootstrap segun el tamaño de la pantalla

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

estoy haciendo un menú transparente encima de un carrousel en bootstrap y me surgen dos problemas. El primero es que la letra del menú es blanca y cuando hago la pantalla pequeña y activo el menú hamburguesa el fondo que me sale es blanco tambien, por lo que no se ven las letras del menú, si cambio el fondo se me cambia en los dos lados, por lo tanto en pantalla grande ya no es transparente. Necesito que sea transparente cuando la pantalla es grande y de color rojo cuando es pequeño.
Por otra parte, cuando la pantalla es grande me sale un margen blanco arriba que no se como quitarlo, en pantalla pequeña el carrousel si llega a la parte de arriba y se ve bien, pero en pantalla grande no. Espero haberme explicado correctamente. Gracias por su ayuda.

```css
/* NAVBAR */
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.my-nav {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff00!important;
  top:30px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:999;
  background: none;
  border:none;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.img-logo{
  width: 100px;
}

.my-nav .navbar-brand {
  color:#fff;
}

.my-nav .navbar-brand:hover,
.my-nav .navbar-brand:focus {
  color:aliceblue;
}

.my-nav .navbar-text {
  color:#fff;
}
.my-nav .navbar-nav >li{
  width: 75%;
  text-align: center;
}

.my-nav .navbar-nav >li >a {
  color:#fff;
  background-color: #c8255b!important;
}

.my-nav .navbar-nav >li >a:hover,
.my-nav .navbar-nav >li >a:focus {
  color: #000!important;
}

.my-nav .navbar-nav >.active >a,
.my-nav .navbar-nav >.active >a:hover,
.my-nav .navbar-nav >.active >a:focus {
  background-color: #3962ff!important;
  color: #3962ff!important;
}

.my-nav .navbar-toogle {
  border-color: #000;
}

.my-nav .navbar-toogle:hover,
.my-nav .navbar-toogle:focus {
  background-color: #000;
}

.my-nav .navbar-toogle-icon {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.my-nav .navbar-collapse{
  border: color #000!important;
}

.my-nav .navbar-link {
  color: #f60a0a!important;
}

.my-nav .navbar-link:hover {
color: #ecdbff;
}

.my-list{
  margin-left: 40%;
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
  .my-nav .navbar-nav .open .dropdown >li >a {
    color: #000!important;
  }
  .my-nav .navbar-nav .open .dropdown >li >a:hover,
  .my-nav .navbar-nav .open .dropdown >li >a:focus {
    color:#ecdbff;
  }
  .my-nav .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active >a,
  .my-nav .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active >a:hover,
  .my-nav .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active >a:focus {
    color: #000!important;
    background-color: #3962ff;
  }
}

.my-carousel{
  bottom: 70px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar my-nav navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
    <div class="container-fluid"><img class="img-logo" src=""></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav my-list me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Qui som</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Serveis</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Treballa amb nosaltres</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Llei de dependència</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacte</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel my-carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/12/21/13/27/forest-7670068__340.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>First slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/10/29/09/27/lake-6751477__340.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Second slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/12/29/08/18/insect-6900940_640.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Third slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Acabo de darme cuenta que en la ejecución de la pregunta no se ve correctamente, se ve el fondo del menú de color grisáceo, no se porque aquí se ve así

Comment: Has probado a ponerle de medida al font-size un 5vw ? ( el 5 es un ejemplo ) ponle un mínimo en pixeles y el resto ampliará dependiendo del ancho de la pantalla. Tal vez te sirva para lo que estás buscando

Comment: Igual no me explicado bien, no es un problema del tamaño de la fuente. El problema es que el fondo del menú es transparente y las letras blancas. En pantalla pequeña el menú es de hamburguesa, que al activarlo se abre hacia abajo dejando un fondo blanco, las letras no se ven porque son blancas. Si cambio el color del fondo o de las letras se me cambia en los dos menús. Quiero tener dos fondos, el del menú normal y el del menú de la hamburguesa. Acabo de darme cuenta que en la ejecución de la pregunta no se ve correctamente, se ve el fondo del menú de color grisáceo, no se porque aquí se ve así

Comment: Revisando el snippet, se vé bien... Significa que en tu proyecto tienes estilos que están generando algún tipo de conflicto.

Comment: Si, si. Pero cuales estilos, no lo logro ver.